# Why in Flutter, PlatformView cannot shrink to its own size?

Tags: android, flutter, interop

For example:

```
child: Row(
  children: [
    const Expanded(child: AndroidNativeView()),
    ElevatedButton(
        child: const Text("PLUS"))
  ],
)
```

In layouts without parent constraints like Flex(Row/Column), The AndroidNativeView (a PlatformViewLink) cannot determine its size thus an exception will be thrown. So the instant solutions are wrapping it inside an Expanded/Flexible, or a Container-like widget with width/height hardcoded. Both solutions are not flexible for the layout.

From the current Dart-side implementations' perspective, I know the `sizedByParent` function of `PlatformViewRenderBox` is overridden to true. So it takes the constraint from parent, without measuring itself, and fill up whatever space it gets.

What I don't understand is, since there is "WRAP_CONTENT" on Android side, what's the reason that they didn't make it possible to shrink a PlatformView to its own size in Flutter? What are the technical difficulties/tradeups?

Comment: you are send   design  Ui   Image

Answer (score 1):

If you use a **Flex(Row/Column)** in a `constraints` independent width like if you don't provide `width/height` to your container then it's child has right to decide that how much space it want to cover in **Row/Column** we've a property named **mainAxisSize** by default it is set to **MainAxisSize.max** but you can set it to min as well then **Row/Column** will also cover space whatever is needed by their `children`.

But if you provide `constraints` to the `parent widget` then as you know already that in **Flutter** constraints goes parent to child so it will cover all the available `space`.

Comment: The flutter's general layout rules does not apply to the PlatformView's case, the mainAxisSize: min parameter does not work either. It will say at runtime: "RenderConstrainedBox object was given an infinite size during layout. This probably means that it is a render object that tries to be as big as possible, but it was put inside another render object that allows its children to pick their own size". The question is about flutter-native interop implementations, not purely flutter layout mechanisms.

Comment: RenderConstrainedBox object was given an infinite size during layout. This error comes when you are adding a column/row inside Listview type object and if you use shrinkwrap it will also get solved and mainAxisSize: min works that's why they exist your use case could be diffrent but it doesn't mean that the property doesn't work